# ssrs report columns not aligning with headers

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

My ssrs report headers are not aligning with the columns when I scroll. Below is the report, as it misaligned when I scroll right, I've tried placing it in a rectangle but that didn't work too.

[image]

I'm trying to freeze the first two columns and want to have the rest scroll through as I scroll right.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the header visible while scrolling, you need to go to **tablix properties > General** and check the option **Keep header visible while scrolling**. Then go to column/row groups in the advanced mode, chose your static row and set the **Fixed Data** mode to `True`, **Repeat on new page** to `True` and **Keep with group** to `After`.

Here is prbably the best reference: [Here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/robertbruckner/2008/10/13/repeat-header-keep-header-visible-in-tables-in-rs-2008/)

Answer (score 1):

By default, everything scrolls together. You may have inadvertently enabled one of the `Keep header visible while scrolling` options in the table properties. The other property that could affect this is if you went into advanced mode in your groups and turned on the `KeepWithGroup` or `KeepTogether` properties. If you set those all back to false, the whole report will scroll together.

Comment: Thank you for your support, I was able to make the whole tablix scroll together. However I'm trying to keep the first two columns static and the rest to scroll through. I tried enabling the 'Advanced mode' and set the 'Fixed Data' property to True but this didn't work. Any other way to achieve this ?