# Reporting Services tablix will not allow me to freeze column header AND Rows

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, rdl

Trying to modify an existing rdl RS report in Visual Studio 2017. It currently freezes the column header when scrolling down, but when I try freeze the four left-most columns so they will stay in view when scrolling right, I get an error that the report definition is invalid. We've successfully done this on another report, and as far as I can tell, the basic setup between the two reports is the same. The only difference I can see is that the report that works doesn't have any grouping on it. Is that the culprit? (I just started a new job... I will be more specific in details once I actually get my own system/logins/etc - it would seem that Higher Ed works a leeeetle more slowly that K-12! - I just wanted to see if there was a quick yes/no answer out there! PS: a "veteran" already gave up on this, so it would be super awesome to fix this as a noob in my new position! ;-))

Comment: I think you will find your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52764073/ssrs-report-columns-not-aligning-with-headers/52772770#52772770

Comment: Yeah, I tried that. Same error: The definition of the report is invalid. The Tablix 'table1' has an incorrectly set FixedHeader property on the opposite hierarchy, based on the property FixedRowHeaders of tablix.

Answer (score 6):

Figured it out!  Removed the "Keep header visible while scrolling" from the Tablix properties. Then changed FixedData to True for the Static Column Groups (Advanced mode). Tested, the column (first name) was frozen. Then in Row Groups, changed FixedData to True for my static header record. Tested. First Name column was frozen, and my headers stayed visible when scrolling H or V. So the Tablix "Keep header visible while scrolling" property was what was gumming up the works.