# Report viewer is not freeze table header in ssrs

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssrs-2008

I am using SSRS report. Click on "View Report" Button report table is display on aspx report.

But according to my client requirement table header should be freeze if scrolling vertically.

I am using report builder for creating .rdl file. when i preview report in report builder table header is freeze and also after uploading on report server table header is freeze. but table header is not freeze once reportviewer is rendar on aspx page.

I have set setting for rdl file in report builder as follow:

**FixData=true, keepWithGroup=After, RepeatOnNewPage=true on row group in advance mode.**

Comment: this may help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/keep-headers-visible-when-scrolling-through-a-report-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I have already followed according to you link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53532765/report-viewer-is-not-freeze-table-header-in-ssrs. But not success.

Comment: This is what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52764073/ssrs-report-columns-not-aligning-with-headers/52772770#52772770

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ssrs report columns not aligning with headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52764073/ssrs-report-columns-not-aligning-with-headers)

Comment: I have done these setting but it work on "Priview" section and on report server when enter server URL on browser. But once i open aspx page where report is bind there header is not freeze, Please give me any suggession.