# SSRS - subreport having group headers across pages?

Tags: reporting-services

My main report has a tablix, where each row is a subreport.

The subreports have row groups.  I’d like the *subreport group headings to repeat across page breaks*.

I’ve followed the advice given elsewhere about using advanced mode to see & modify the “static” groups:

- RepeatOnNewPage = True
- KeepWithGroup = After
- FixedData = True

Yet the subreport group headings display once but don’t print again on subsequent pages.  Are subreports “aware” of the current page scope?  Are SSRS inner containers even aware of page breaks?

Comment: This one is probably the best reference. And check the link in the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52764073/ssrs-report-columns-not-aligning-with-headers/52772770#52772770#

Comment: @Strawberryshrub, thanks for the info!  That link addresses viewing headings while scrolling.  But I'm trying to work with the printed page.  I think I'll solve this by creating a "generic heading" rdl which each subreport will use.  Subreports will be able to populate portions of that rdl as needed.